# THREEJS Can't clone FBX model

Tags: javascript, three.js, 3d, fbx

I am loading FBX models for my project. I Want to create multiple objects of the same FBX model but loading each separately is very inefficient so I would like to save one loaded model and clone it. This concept is working with the .OBJ format.

Everything works as expected but then I use "model.clone();" nothing really happens.
The model is no longer visible but I get no errors. If you compare the cloned model with the original they look exactly the same so I don't know why it's not showing up.

This is how it looks when it's working:

[image]

When it's not working it's just a blank canvas.

Here is some simplified working source code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
</head>
<body>
<script src="https://vitalkia.com/jsLibraries/zlib.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://threejs.org/build/three.js"></script>
<script src="https://threejs.org/examples/js/loaders/FBXLoader.js"> 
</script>
<script>
    var aspectRatio = 240 / 135;
    var scene;
    var renderer;
    var loaderFBX;
    var camera = new THREE.PerspectiveCamera(45, aspectRatio, 1, 10000);




    //Actual code
    //Setus up scene and renderer
    sceneSetup();

    //Load fbx and render
    //IGNORE ERROR ABOUT NOT FINDING THE RIGHT TEXTURE. It still works
    loaderFBX.load("https://threejs.org/examples/models/fbx/Samba Dancing.fbx", function(model){
        //Sending the object "model" works
        //But using model.clone() does not. It doesn't give any errors or anything, it's just not visible
        //If you compare the cloned model with the original they look exactly the same.

        var sendModel = model;//Works
        //var sendModel = model.clone();//Doesn't works
        console.log("Original: ");
        console.log(model);
        console.log("Cloned: ");
        console.log(model.clone());

        calcDistance(sendModel);

        scene.add(sendModel);
        renderer.render(scene, camera);
    });




    function calcDistance(model){
        var bbox = new THREE.Box3().setFromObject(model);

        var camDistance = bbox.max.z;
        if(bbox.max.x > camDistance){
            camDistance = bbox.max.x;
        }
        if(bbox.max.y*aspectRatio > camDistance){
            camDistance = bbox.max.y*aspectRatio;
        }

        camera.position.z = camDistance;
        model.position.x -= bbox.getCenter().x;
        model.position.y -= bbox.getCenter().y;
    }


    function sceneSetup(){
        loaderFBX = new THREE.FBXLoader();
        scene = new THREE.Scene();
        renderer = new THREE.WebGLRenderer({antialias: true, alpha: true});
        renderer.setSize(240, 135);
        document.body.appendChild(renderer.domElement);
        var light1 = new THREE.PointLight(0xffffff, 1, 100000000);
        light1.position.set(0, 0, 15);
        scene.add(light1);
        var newLightPoint = new THREE.HemisphereLight(0x8be2ff, 0xfff9cf, 0.55);
        scene.add(newLightPoint);
        camera.position.set(0, 0, 100);
        scene.add(camera);
    }
</script>
```

Is this how you should do it to reuse models instead of having to reload them for every object? Or is there a better way?

Comment: I wonder, there is no solution even after 4 years. Right now I am also facing same issue.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Three.js clone FBX with animation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50792178/three-js-clone-fbx-with-animation)